# Getting the response from AJAX request and inserting it into outgoing link

Tags: jquery, ajax

All outgoing traffic from my site gets entered into a database. I want to then put the ID of the inserted row into the outgoing link href. The URLs have a variable in them called $id like example.com?id=$id. I want to replace that $id with the inserted row's id like example.com?id=114.

I'm inserting into the db fine but I have a hard time from there. I've found many similar questions to mine but they don't seem to fit exactly. How can I get the value from the "process" function so I can append it to the link?

So far this is what I have. Any advice is welcome!

```
jQuery('a[href^="http"]').not('[href*="' + window.location.host + '"]').on('click', function(e) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      data: {
        action: 'the_ajax_hook',
        source: jQuery.cookie('source'),
        destination: jQuery(this).attr("href"),
        },
      type: 'post',
      url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
      success: function(data) {
        process(data);
      }
    });

    function process(data) {
      //?????
    }
    jQuery(this).attr('href',jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('$id',id));

    //for testing
    console.log(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the `href` doesn't work, because the callback function operates asynchronously.

Instead, assign to `window.location` to redirect to the new URL instead of performing the default action of the link.

```
jQuery('a[href^="http"]').not('[href*="' + window.location.host + '"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link automatically
  let url = jQuery(this).attr("href");
  jQuery.ajax({
    data: {
      action: 'the_ajax_hook',
      source: jQuery.cookie('source'),
      destination: url,
    },
    type: 'post',
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    success: function(data) {
      process(url, data);
    }
  });
});

function process(url, data) {
  let target = url.replace('$id', data);
  window.location = target;
}
```

Comment: Oh this almost gets me there but I'm trying to open all these links in a new tab, so window.location isn't what I want to use. I think I understand how you did it though.

Comment: Use `window.open()` instead. Although a popup blocker may prevent that in the callback.

Comment: Ah yes that does it Thank you! Where can I find a basic primer on callbacks and asynchronality? Learning from Stack Overflow isn't going to work for me.

Comment: Sorry, don't know good learning resources.